# Show provider hosted app page in modal popup

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app

I want to show provider hosted app page in modal pop-up from host web.

Comment: R u able to find the solution..?

Answer (score 0):

we can use **JavaScript** with  **OpenPopUpPageWithTitle** to achieve this requirement

`javascript:OpenPopUpPageWithTitle('https://ProviderAppUrl/Controller/Action?SPHostUrl={SiteUrl}&ItemUrl={ItemUrl}&IsDlg=1', RefreshOnDialogClose, 800, 600,'Start a process'`)"

please check the link[Show SharePoint Provider Hosted page in Modal Window with callback](https://moopoo.wordpress.com/2015/11/27/show-sharepoint-provider-hosted-page-in-modal-window-with-callback/)

Comment: i get below error : 
An error occurred while processing your request.

Comment: Are you able to open that provider hosted page normally when browsing the provider hosted web (not using a dialog)?